# Passing PHP variables into Flot charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, flot

How would I display values on a Flot bar chart using my PHP variables, rather than using static data? I am not sure if the PHP has to be inside the JavaScript or how it should be formatted.

Afterwards, I would like to echo my variables inside the var `data`.

For example, instead of saying...

```
$london = mysqli_num_rows($londonc); 
$Newyourk = mysqli_num_rows($Newyourkc);
$Taipei = mysqli_num_rows($Taipei);
$NewDelhi= mysqli_num_rows($NewDelhi); 

var data = [   
    [0, 11], //London, UK
    [1, 15], //New York, USA
    [2, 25], //New Delhi, India
    [3, 24], //Taipei, Taiwan
    [4, 13], //Beijing, China
    [5, 18]  //Sydney, AU
];
```

...I'd like to use my PHP variables in a way something like this:

```
var data = [    
    [0, <?php echo '['.($London).']'?>], //London
    [1, <?php echo '['.($NewYork).']'?>], //New York
    [2, <?php echo '['.($NewDelhi,).']'?>], //New Delhi,
    [3, <?php echo '['.($Taipei).']'?>], //Taipei
    [4, <?php echo '['.($Beijing).']'?>] //Beijing
];
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping your second value in array brackets `[]` when the first example suggests you just need to echo out an integer value? Also, is the value of `$London` an integer?

Comment: @Darragh is right, I misread your post. That is your issue.

Comment: That is to say, assuming `$London` contains the integer value `11` and you are trying to replicate your first example. You are outputting `[0, [11]]` which is different to your first example.

Comment: I am trying to display my php string variables into a flot chart but still with no succeeded .Any idea ?

Comment: string values are quoted?

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil actually it is integer php variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, i have tested this code and its working fine

```
<link href="../examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php       
            $London = 3; 
            $NewYork = 8;
            $NewDelhi = 5; 
            $Taipei = 13;          
        ?>
        $(function() {
            var d2 = [[0, <?php echo $London; ?>], [4, <?php echo $NewDelhi; ?>], [8, <?php echo $NewYork; ?>], [9, <?php echo $Taipei; ?>]];
            $.plot("#placeholder", [ d2]);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo-container" id="placeholder">           
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution already but doesn't work my dear.Any idea

Comment: can you see the values in page source and how it looks?

Comment: The values have to be displayed in a flot chart like any charts. flot chart working for me when I use static data like numbers for example var data = [    
       [0,  454], 
       [1,  87], 
       [2,  343], 
       [3,  43], 
       [4,  3] 
       ];. but when I try to echo my php variabes in the var data doesn't display anything I also noticed that my php variables working great with charts.js but not working when I use flot charts.

Comment: @Печальный Мир modified the answer, please check it, i have tested and its working perfectly

Comment: Thank you that was great solution.Is it possible you click on one of the bar data chart and linked you to a another php page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `json_encode()` in this case. No need to to it by hand:

```
<?php

$London = 11;
$NewYork = 15;
$NewDelhi = 25;
$Taipei = 24;
$Beijing = 13;
$Sydnew = 18;

$values = array(
    array(0, $London),
    array(1, $NewYork),
    array(2, $NewDelhi),
    array(3, $Taipei),
    array(4, $Beijing),
    array(5, $Sydnew),
);

$data = json_encode($values);
echo $data; // [[0,11],[1,15],[2,25],[3,24],[4,13],[5,18]]

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
console.log(data);
</script>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L3q9Sj)

Comment: @ПечальныйМир you mean like `[0, [11]]`? check my addition on the answer

Comment: I am tying to display my php string variables into a flot chart but still with no succeeded.

Comment: @ПечальныйМир what should `data` look like in the end?

Comment: data will be displayed into flot charts exactly when you use static data. I have the flot charts displayed when I used static data like number but I'd like to use my php variables rather than static variables.

Comment: Here for example if I use static variable like var data =
    [   
    [0, 1], 
    [1, 400], 
    
    [2, 5435]
 
    ];
but when I use my php variables my flot chart not displaying anything

Comment: @ПечальныйМир yes i understand that, of course instead of hardcoding values, you would rather using dynamic data coming from PHP. what i mean is. what would `var data=` look like in the end, so that it will become usable for flot. is it like this? `var data = [[0, 10], [0, 20]]` ... etc. ?

Comment: Yes exactly like that but instead of 10 or 20 would be php variables.

Comment: @ПечальныйМир edit your question, and put the PHP codes also, i'd like to see how you are generating those data

Comment: I added few lines of code how I generated those variables

Comment: @ПечальныйМир doesn't seem much different from what i've done besides from the differences in the variable names: `$london` and `$London`. check out my edit and my live demo on the answer

Comment: thanks so much my dear for your kind help, I will give it a try again. Thanks again

Comment: @ПечальныйМир sure im glad i was able to help

Comment: I tried your code and I echo $data and the output is[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0]] where my $data has values stored in database and chart still not displaying.